# Omit module names from cross-reference to classes

Tags: python, python-sphinx, cross-reference

#### Background

I have a project called [ciscoconfparse](https://github.com/mpenning/ciscoconfparse), which is documented with [Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/); the documentation for the project is [here](http://www.pennington.net/py/ciscoconfparse/index.html).

The [source code directory](https://github.com/mpenning/ciscoconfparse/tree/master/ciscoconfparse) has multiple files:

- `ciscoconfparse.py` contains the classes `CiscoConfParse` and `IOSConfigList`
- `models_cisco.py` contains a class called `IOSCfgLine`

This is an example of how I'm documenting `IOSCfgLine`...

```
.. module:: models_cisco

IOSCfgLine Object
-----------------

.. autoclass:: IOSCfgLine
      :members:
      :inherited-members:
```

The existing Sphinx documentation has class hyperlinks that are hideous, including both the file name and the class name; one example is `models_cisco.IOSCfgLine`.

***Example documentation screenshot:***
[image]

#### Question

How can I use `autoclass` to document classes in the various Python files and *only* see the class name in the rendered documentation, instead of the file name included with the class?  In other words, I just want to see hyperlinks to `IOSCfgLine` instead of `models_cisco.IOSCfgLine`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To only see the the name itself in links, you can use the `~` in links:

```
:class:`~models_cisco.IOSCfgLine`
```

this will render as `IOSCfgLine` instead of `models_cisco.IOSCfgLine`.

---

But as, if I see it correctly in your codebase, all classes are available in the toplevel package name space. So you can also document them like that (so without the `.. module:: models_cisco`, but `.. module:: ciscoconfparse`).